# Python w/QT Creator form - Possible to grab multiple values?

Tags: forms, qt, python-3.x

I'm surprised to not find a previous question about this, but I did give an honest try before posting.

I've created a ui with Qt Creator which contains quite a few QtWidgets of type QLineEdit, QTextEdit, and QCheckbox.  I've used pyuic5 to convert to a .py file for use in a small python app.  I've successfully got the form connected and working, but this is my first time using python with forms.

I'm searching to see if there is a built-in function or object that would allow me to pull the ObjectNames and Values of all widgets contained within the GUI form and store them in a dictionary with associated keys:values, because I need to send off the information for post-processing.

I guess something like this would work manually:

```
...
dict = []
dict['checkboxName1'] = self.checkboxName1.isChecked()
dict['checkboxName2'] = self.checkboxName2.isChecked()
dict['checkboxName3'] = self.checkboxName3.isChecked()
dict['checkboxName4'] = self.checkboxName4.isChecked()
dict['lineEditName1'] = self.lineEditName1.text()
... and on and on
```

But is there a way to grab all the objects and loop through them, even if each different type (i.e. checkboxes, lineedits, etc) needs to be done separately?

I hope I've explained that clearly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working.  Couldn't find a python specific example anywhere, so through trial and error this worked perfectly.  I'm including the entire working code of a .py file that can generate a list of all QCheckBox objectNames on a properly referenced form.

I named my form main_form.ui from within Qt Creator.  I then converted it into a .py file with pyuic5

```
pyuic5 main_form.ui -o main_form.py
```

This is the contents of a sandbox.py file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import main_form
# the name of my Qt Creator .ui form converted to main_form.py with pyuic5
# pyuic5 original_form_name_in_creator.ui -o main_form.py


class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, main_form.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Push button object on main_form named btn_test
        self.btn_test.clicked.connect(self.runTest)

    def runTest(self):
        # I believe this creates a List of all QCheckBox objects on entire UI page
        c = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QCheckBox)
        # This is just to show how to access objectName property as an example
        for box in c:
            print(box.objectName())


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # A new instance of QApplication
    form = MainApp()  # We set the form to be our ExampleApp (design)
    form.show()  # Show the form
    app.exec_()  # and execute the app


if __name__ == '__main__':  # if we're running file directly and not importing it
    main()  # run the main function
```

Answer (score 1):

See `QObject::findChildren()`

In C++ the template argument would allow one to specify which type of widget to retrieve, e.g. to just retrieve the `QLineEdit` objects, but I don't know if or how that is mapped into Python.

Might need to retrieve all types and then switch handling while iterating over the resulting list.